# Initialize configuration in unit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, jersey, initialization, singleton

I met some troubles with the initialization in the unit test. I have been stuck with this problem for a while.

I have an EventProcessor class and it is a singleton class. In the constructor, I call a method which will read the config file.

```
public class EventProcessor{

 // SingletonHolder is a container class to hold singleton instance 
private static final SingletonHolder<EventProcessor> m_EventProcessor = new SingletonHodler<>(new EventProcessor());

private EventProcessor() {
 Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
 String scheme = requiredHttps() ? "https" : "http";
 m_webTarget = client.target(scheme + ....);
}

// this method will get the singleton instance of this class
public static EventProcessor getAuditEventProcessor() {
    return m_EventProcessor.instance();
}

protected boolean requiredHttps() {
   // Configuration class is also a singleton and getConfig() is a static method
   //getSettings() will get key-value pair in the config file
  Map map = Configuration.getConfig().getSettings();  
  //do some check with the value in the map
 }
}
```

So when I start the whole project, another class will initialize the Configuration class and I can read the config file by using requiredHttps(). Everything works fine. But the problem is when I write the unit test, Configuration class cannot be initialized. So when I do something like 
EventProcessor.getAuditEventProcessor() in the test class and get the ExceptionInInitializerError, cannot initialize the EventProcessor class because of getting a NullPointerException from Configuration.getConfig().getSettings();

Any suggestion about that?

Answer (score 0):

You can create `static` method to initialize `Configuration` and annotate that method with `@BeforeClass`. Such method will be executed before all methods in your test class.